# Attribute vs constant access in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm working on High-performance oriented web components and I doubt if it's worths assign an object attribute's value to a constant before accessing it multiple times.

I mean turning this:

```js
let counter = 0;
for (let i = 0, len = parentObject.myObject.items.length; i < len; i++) {
    // items is an array of integers
    counter += parentObject.myObject.items[i] ;
}
```

Into this:

```js
let counter = 0;
const { myObject } = parentObject;
const { items } = myObject;
for (let i = 0, len =items.length; i < len; i++) { 
    counter += items[i] ;
}
```

In Python this change would have a sentitive impact in performance. However the tests I have made (code at https://gist.github.com/Edorka/fbfb0778c859d8f518f0508414d3e6a2) shows no difference:

```
caseA total 124999750000
Execution time (hr): 0s 1.88101ms
caseB total 124999750000
Execution time (hr): 0s 1.117547ms
```

I doubt if I'm making my tests wrong or if the VM has any optimization for this case I'm not aware of.

UPDATE: Following @George Jempty suggestion I made a quick adaptation on JSPerf at https://jsperf.com/attribute-vs-constants but results keep being  quite erratic.

Comment: ok but on repeated tests the results are quite erratic: 14 vs 4, 2 vs 2.8, etc etc in some tests, the B case is slower than B case

Comment: Have you tried jsperf?

Comment: What kind of declaration is this? `const { myObject }`?

Comment: @RickardElimää it is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: It's a ES6 asignation from an object's attribute

Comment: Damn, I need to really update myself on ES6. Thanks for the fast responses! I couldn't run the code, hence asking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested property access is one of the most frequently executed operation in JavaScript. You can expect it to be heavily optimized.

Indeed, the V8 engine [caches](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties) object properties at run time, so the performance benefit of caching manually would be negligible.

[Live demo on jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/58933886/1)

[image: no difference]

Conclusion: don't worry about it!